# docker-compose error "read-only file system"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I designed a `docker-compose.yml` file that also supposed to work with individual volumes.

I created a raid-drive which is mounted as `/dataraid` to my system. I can read/write to the system, but when using it in my compose file, I get `read-only file system` error messages.

Adjusting the volumes to a other path like `/home/myname/test` the compose file works.

I have no idea what the `/dataraid` makes it "read-only".

What are the permissions settings a compose file needs?

error message:

```
ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: error while creating mount source path '/dataraid/nextcloud/mariadb': mkdir /dataraid: read-only file system
```

compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
    env_file:
      - db.env
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/html:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
    env_file:
      - db.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  web:
    build: ./web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/html:/var/www/html:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=name.de
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=name.de
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=x@y.de
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 4080:80
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
      - default
  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    expose:
       - 9980
    cap_add:
      - MKNOD
    environment:
      - domain=name.de
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=name.de
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=9980
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=https
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=name.de
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=x@y.de
      - username=            #optional
      - password=       #optional
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always
  cron:
    build: ./app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/html:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: /cron.sh
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=https
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=443
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    volumes:
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
  letsencrypt-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    depends_on:
      - proxy
networks:
  proxy-tier:
```

see error messages:

```
bernd@sys-dock:/dataraid/Docker-Configs/nextcloud$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "nextcloud_default" with the default driver
Creating network "nextcloud_proxy-tier" with the default driver
Creating nextcloud_db_1 ...
Creating nextcloud_proxy_1     ... error
Creating nextcloud_db_1        ... error
Creating nextcloud_collabora_1 ...
ERROR: for nextcloud_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: error while creating mount source path '/dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-certs': mkdir /dataraid: read-only file system
Creating nextcloud_redis_1     ... done
Creating nextcloud_collabora_1 ... done
ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: error while creating mount source path '/dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-certs': mkdir /dataraid: read-only file system
ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: error while creating mount source path '/dataraid/nextcloud/mariadb': mkdir /dataraid: read-only file system
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Can you post your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Doesn't sound like anything to do with docker, more to do with how that drive is configured / mounted. Can you create regular files on the mount (without using Docker)?

Comment: see my docker-compose.yml

Comment: @johnharris85: that is the strange part. I can touch and modify files in that mounted drive...

Comment: You're mounting the volumes as readonly...? `- /dataraid/nextcloud/nginx-certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro`. RO = read-only...

Comment: @johnharris85 only some are marked as RO. for reverse proxy and also for certificates.      I was thinking like you, but a remove of the RO didnt help, also when I kept the RO and used another volume, it worked......

Comment: Did you mount the dataraid filesystem after docker started? If so, try restarting the docker daemon (`systemctl restart docker`)

Comment: looks like a restart of the docker demon worked it out.... strange! I thought I did a reboot of the entire engine anyway.....
THANKS TO ALL and BMitch

Comment: @BMitch you should add your comment as an answer so it could be accepted and easier to be found. +1 from me and thanks!

Answer (score 22):

If docker starts before the filesystem gets mounted, you could be seeing issues with the docker engine trying to write to the parent filesystem. You can restart the docker daemon to rule this out (`systemctl restart docker` in systemd base environments).

If restarting the daemon helps, then you can add a dependency between the docker engine and the external filesystem mounts. In systemd, that involves an `After=` clause in the unit file. E.g. you could create a `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` file containing:

```
[Unit]
After=nfs-client.target
```

(Note that I'm not sure that `nfs-client.target` is the correct unit file for your 
filesystem, you'll want to check where it gets mounted.)

---

Another issue I've seen people encounter recently is Snap based docker installs, which run docker inside of another container technology, which would prevent access to paths not explicitly configured in the Snap.

Comment: That was exactly my issue, had used snap.

Comment: The problem was resolved just after re-installing the docker. In my case, the shared storage had been mounted after docker installation.

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing `:ro` to `:rw` in my `docker-compose.yml` was the key to enabling write permissions.

In your case (for example--I'm not sure this is your issue):

```
  web:
    build: ./web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /dataraid/nextcloud/html:/var/www/html:ro # change to :rw
```

With `:ro` on my case, I saw:

```
$ docker exec --privileged -it x_api bash
root@api# touch foo
touch: cannot touch 'foo': Read-only file system
```

But after using `:rw` and restarting the container, `touch` worked.